# Convert join data to Beans returned from oracle procedure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a procedure in oracle that returns join data from multiple tables. Something similar to following procedure

```
create or replace procedure MyProc(curs OUT sys_refcursor)
as
begin
open curs for
select one.name, one.email, two.address, two.phone_no from table1 one INNER JOIN table2 two
ON one.id=two.id;
end;
/
```

The procedure actually returns 8 colums from first table and 5 from second, after processing on other tables.

Now I don't want to map the returned data to a class in my hibernate mapping file. But yet when I call the procedure the returned data should be converted into the Beans. Say for above procedure I use following files.

**Bean.java** to hold returned data

```
class Bean
 {
  String name;
  String email;
  String address;
  long phone_no;
 .....
//getter and setters
 }
```

**Bean.hbm.xml** for hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<sql-query name="temp" callable="true">
{call MyProc(?)}
</sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Call.java** from where I call my procedure

```
public class Call
{
 @Autowired
 SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 public List<Bean> get()
  {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query=session.getNamedQuery("temp");
    List<Bean> list;//The result should be converted to a list of Bean
    session.close();
    return list;
  }
}
```

From where I call my procedure I want the returned data to be converted into a list of Bean class.

How is it possible to do it.

I am using **Hibernate 3.0** and **Spring 3.0**

Comment: Oh it is a method of Session interface. Please correct you comment.

Comment: OK, I see, it is from `SharedSessionContract`.. btw. `org.hibernate.Session` is an interface

Comment: Now to that I can comply.

Comment: You'll need to embed another List for two.address, two.phone_no in Bean.

Answer (score -1):

Now to answer your question.
try this:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getNamedQuery("temp")
    .addScalar("name", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
    .addScalar("email", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
    .addScalar("address", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
    .addScalar("phone_no", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Bean.class));
```

But I will recommend the way to let spring call the SP and use `RowMapper` to do the rest, check out the link: [Calling a stored procedure with SimpleJdbcCall](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-1)

**UPDATE**

Then try:

```
List rawList = sessionFactory.getNamedQuery("temp")
    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Bean.class)).list();
return (List<Bean>) rawList;
```

Comment: By the way I am using hibernate 3.0

Comment: And I cannot find addScalar in it.

Comment: @DarshanLila then try only use the transformer, it may also work

Comment: There is no Transformers also.

Comment: @DarshanLila hmm.. give me the version number of your `hibernate-core`